# In an equilateral $ABC$, $P$ is an interior point such that $AP^2=BP^2+CP^2$. Find $\angle BPC.$

Tags: geometry

> In an equilateral triangle $ABC$, $P$ is an interior point such that $AP^2=BP^2+CP^2$. Find $\angle BPC.$

I thought if $BC=AP$ then angle $BPC$ is right angle. But it must be greater than AP so angle is greater than $90.$ I know answer is $150$ but how?

Comment: **Hint:** The geometric locus of *P* is a circle passing through *BC*.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

Rotate $P$ about $B$ to obtain $P'$so that $\Delta PAB\cong\Delta PCB$. Observe that $PP'=P'B$, you can find a triangle where the Pythagoras Theorem is applicable.

Answer (score 3):

Rotate the triangle $BPA$ by $60^0$ to get a triangle $BP'C$. Then $BP=BP'$ and $\angle PBP'=60^0$, so triangle $PBP$ is equilateral, hence $PP'=BP$. Clearly $CP'=AP$. So $CP'^2=AP^2+P'P^2$, so triangle $CPP'$ is right. Now it's easy to get $\angle CPB=\angle CPP'+\angle P'PB=90^0+60^0=150^0$.

[image]

Comment: How did you get the image?

Comment: @FriendIndeed Given the diagram, I think he's rotating the triangle $\Delta ABC$, with $B$ as the center and by $60^{\deg}$ until $\Delta PBA$ coincides with $\Delta P'BC$.

Comment: @FriendIndeed If you are asking what software I used to create the image, I have used GeoGebra, which is a free (and, in my opinion, amazing!) tool for creating geometric drawings.

Comment: Wojuwu i think your solution is a little ambigous as we don't know if △ BPA will coincide with △BP'C if u rotate 60 degree

Comment: @FriendIndeed The point P' is _defined_ so that after rotating BPA by 60 degrees you get BP'C.

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture.

Point $P$ must be closer to $B$ and $C$ than it is to point $A$. This is most easily seen if the line $AP$ bisects the triangle (making $BP$ and $CP$ equal). At that point, the height of the triangle $ABC$, minus the length of $AP$, gives us the height of the triangle $BCP$. Knowing the height and the length of all three sides of $BCP$ at this point is more than enough to determine the angles.